# Dragging a div via touch - very slow

Tags: javascript, css, html, touch

I'm trying to make a draggable div.

**Javascript code Snippet:**

```
document.getElementById('mySidenav').addEventListener('touchmove',
   function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();

       clickX = event.touches[event.touches[0].identifier].pageX;

       if(navigationOpen){          
        //draggable.style.width = Math.floor(clickX) + 'px';
        document.getElementById('mySidenav').setAttribute("style","width:"+ clickX + "px");
    }

}, false);
```

Now there are 2 problems:

1) The drag doesn't work until I stop moving (not necessarily ending touch)

2) There's also a bit of lag when the `<div>` is moving.

I check to see the movement by outputing my `clickX` and it works fine under 30fps

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to do this?

UPDATE:
I'm running this program in Cordova on Android

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use jQuery? Or specifically jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for the help. For some reason the solution was to delete code from CSS

```
.sideNav {
    ...
    ...

    transition: 0.5s; /* This */
}
```

But now there is no fluent animation when the sideNav is closing/opening :(

Answer (score 2):

You didn't paste your HTML so here's just a quick example of a draggable div which works really well on touch devices.

```js
var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('dragme');

for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  var obj = nodeList[i];
  obj.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    event.target.style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';
    event.target.style.top = touch.pageY + 'px';
    event.preventDefault();
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.dragme {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="dragme"></div>
```

There is no mouse events here so it will only work on touch but hopefully this example can be useful to you.

Fiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/fjmn0pej/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed help, I did manage to make it work, maybe you can help with other problem? :)

Comment: Sure, ask away! I will look at your other question on monday the latest :)